How do I keep persistent web socket connections with another API in my Django app?
I'm developing a Django application that requires a persistent WebSocket connection to continuously fetch live data from a crypto market API. I need to keep this WebSocket connection active throughout the application's lifecycle to update my local data as new information arrives. This updated data will later be displayed on the front end, so I anticipate needing a separate WebSocket connection between the front end and back end (one connection for backend-to-crypto market API, and another for backend-to-frontend).
I'm new to this type of setup and would appreciate guidance on the best practices for implementing it. I've explored Django Channels, Uvicorn, and Daphne. Although Django Channels might be suitable for the frontend-backend WebSocket connection, I'm more focused on maintaining a robust event-loop structure for the backend-to-crypto API connection to ensure it remains alive and responsive. I'm considering building a custom event-loop manager to handle this, but I'm unsure if it's the best approach.
Could you suggest any established methods, libraries, or patterns for maintaining a continuous WebSocket connection for real-time data updates in a Django application?
Thank you in advance!
